# How do you pronounce "the Jones'"

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce "the Jones'"? as it pertains to the following:

"Mr. Jones and the rest of his family enjoyed the party, therefore the Jones' plans for another party were eagerly anticipated."

Comment: That could as well be "the Joneses," as in *keeping up with the Joneses.*

Comment: @Kris - That's an answer if not *the* answer. You should post it as one.

Comment: Well, it's a wrong answer, so just as well not to post it. The pronunciation is correct, but "joneses" is not what was meant in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, as detailed in the comments, the answer is *The Joneses*, pronounced /**ˈdʒoʊnzɨz**/ or /**ˈdʒoʊnzəz**/ (JONE-zez).

**dʒ** as in ***j***am. **oʊ** as in *g**o***. **n** as in *ca**n***. **z** as in *ha**s***.  **ɨ** as in *ros**e**s* OR **ə** as in *foc**u**s*. **z** as in *ha**s***.

Comment: You're right. I'll change that.

Comment: I'd not be quite that fast. Certainly if it were /ˈdʒoʊnzəz/, it would have been actually written as *Joneses* or *Jones's*. But it's written as *Jones'*, so apparently the pronunciation the author had in mind was /ˈdʒoʊnz/. Same as with *Jesus'* vs. *Jesus's*, *James'* vs. *James's*. We have many prior questions on this.

Comment: @RegDwigнt _Jones’_ is entirely equivalent to _Jones’s_ to many people (myself included). It is the possessive of _Jones_. In this case, it’s a plural possessive, so I would probably have written it _Joneses’_; but the orthographic representation of pluralised family names ending in sibilants is notoriously random and all over the place, so that’s hardly conclusive.